# Creating products and inventing during employment and assignment of inventions

Tags: intellectual-property

(I need to ask this question again since I did not have enough information last time. Now I have access to full set of documents I signed including: NDA, Assignment of inventions etc....)

If I create a product-idea outside of reasonable office hours using my own resources (Money, computer, code-base etc...) will assignment of inventions I signed with my employer prevent me from claiming full rights to my invention?

I also want to make sure that I can use this code-base later to productionize my invention and sell it to enterprise customers later when I leave my current employer.

If it helps the following section applies and is mentioned in my agreement:
CALIFORNIA LABOR CODE SECTION 2870

However I have to mention that I work from GA

How will my "Assignment of Inventions Agreement" harm me? I am happy to provide more details on request...

Comment: @George White Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assignment of Inventions with Employer](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/40680/assignment-of-inventions-with-employer)

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Thanks! I would like to discuss this afresh as last time I asked the question I did not have all the information . Now I have full documentation to back complete discussion.

Comment: Is this new product idea/code base related to the work that your employer does?

Comment: @RonBeyer It depends on your definition of the word "related". The science itself behind the idea coincides with some of the initiatives of the employer. However the technology and implementation is done ground up and is fully organic. None of the implementation details borrow any ideas from technology of my employer.

Comment: Then I believe you absolutely open yourself up to lawsuits from your employer claiming at least some of the intellectual property rights of the work. Would your customers be the same as your employers customers? Is it in a similar or related field? Would it be reasonable to assume your employer would find the invention useful towards its primary business?

Comment: @RonBeyer How can employers claim the entire science as their own? If my employer is in computer security business developing intrusion signatures for its platform and I develop a much faster platform with my own code stack and own intrusion signatures, that I researched and developed myself entirely - then the employer cannot claim all that to be its own just because my initiative was in the same general area as company's business.

Comment: They cannot claim the entire discipline to be its own, can they?

Comment: @RonBeyer Having said that to your other questions, it is unlikely that future customers would be same as my employers, thought I do not want to rule it out.

Comment: No, of course not. But they employ you to be an expert in that discipline and to further *their business* in that discipline. If you invent something that the employer would find useful, in the employers field, and in its primary business while you are employed then they have a very legitimate claim to that work, even if the work was done outside business hours. That is what the "assignment of inventions" was designed to protect from the employers standpoint.

Comment: @RonBeyer I quite dont agree. But that doesn't matter. Even the state of CA doesnt seem to agree with what you stated. See "CALIFORNIA LABOR CODE SECTION 2870"

Comment: As far as I understand that section of CA law clearly forbids employer from claiming employee inventions done in his spare time using his/her own resources.

Comment: Unless I use employers trade secrets/resources/assets etc...

Comment: I know the code, the sticking point is this: *"This does not apply, however, to inventions that either: (1) relate at the time of conception or reduction to practice of the invention to the employer’s business, or actual or **demonstrably anticipated research** or development of the employer"*

Comment: @RonBeyer But what if I was never involved in that "actual or nticipated research" ? What if initial application of my idea is in a business that is completely different from my employers line of business?

Comment: Because if I work for a hi tech company and I create something tech after work, there will be some overlap. Because at bare minimum we would use at least a small subset of coding technologies as the company.

Comment: There is no way to completely steer clear.

Answer (score 1):

If what you do falls within the scope of the assignment clause and that clause is reasonably necessary to protect the employer’s interests (i.e. it is limited in scope) then they will own the IP.

For example, if your employer is an accounting firm and what you produce is accounting software they will own it. If what you produce is a game or an operating system for a Mars rover, they won’t. If what you produce is a pricing model for financial derivatives, it could go either way.

Comment: So then, the idea is to steer clear of the employer's "line of business". If my employer is into Tax Filing Software and I do HR Payroll software, then I should be fine, correct? Otherwise they should not be able to argue that I learnt and used Java during employment and used the same language to develop my HR Payroll Software; hence they own my invention! That would be absurd.